# Duplicate rows but 1 column has different value. Keep only rows that are duplicate and have a specific column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe:

```
channelId | topic
a         | 1
a         | 0
b         | 0
b         | 1
c         | 0
d         | 1
```

I need to remove all duplicate rows that have a topic value == 0.

So end result should be:

```
channelId | topic
a         | 1
b         | 1
c         | 0
d         | 1
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`series.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`series.eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df[~(df['channelId'].duplicated(keep=False)&df['topic'].eq(0))]
```

---

```
  channelId  topic
0         a      1
3         b      1
4         c      0
5         d      1
```